# CSS Cross-Browser Curved Borders

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the correct/best way to define cross-browser CSS/CSS3 compliant/valid curved borders?

Is there a non-JavaScript way of doing so, while being cross-browser compatible? If not, is there any proper workaround?

Comment: Correct way? `border-radius`. Best in terms of compatibility? Images.

Comment: Do you care if IE users don't get a really pretty site? Figure out how much you care and then weigh that up against how much extra work it is to get it to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px
```

together? That should cover the primary 3 browsers in their latest releases (at least). Without javascript or using images, you're not going to get full cross-browser coverage.

Answer (score 2):

See the [CSS Border Radius Generator](http://border-radius.com/) (simple rounded corners) or [CSS3 Please](http://css3please.com/) (more effects) for a CSS-only solution. If you want something that works in Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+ with **no images** then try [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/). Here's a [nice talk by Dmitry Baranovskiy](http://blip.tv/file/3731552/), author of Raphaël, explaining why it's cool.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is with border-radius.

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px
```

This is only compatible in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. This does not work for IE 7+8 (and less)

If you want the most compatibility but the least amount of flexibility, images are the way to go.

If you want flexibility and browser compatibility go with javascript. The best one I have found converts the CSS3 declatation to rounder corners in IE 7+8.

Check that one out here: http://www.curvycorners.net/

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px
```

WebKit has supported plain `border-radius` for a while now.

http://css3generator.com/ for example, has dropped the `-webkit` prefix.

To make this work in Internet Explorer, I recommend using [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), which is as simple as downloading a small file, and adding this to your CSS:

```
behavior: url(PIE.htc)
```

Of course, this will only work when Javascript is turned on in IE (which is usually the case).